# Java Class dependent on some parameter

Tags: java, class, generics

Is it possible to create "generic" class in Java that would depend on some parameter (instead of a type)? Something like this:

```
 class RVector<int n>
 {
      double[] v = new double[n];

      public RVector<int n>(double[] d){
      //...
      }

      //...
 }
```

which for each integer n would simulate a real vector with n components.
If not, is there something similar to this in Java?

Comment: No, that feature is called either type-level literals or [dependent typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), depending on how far you want to take it. Java doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly with generics, but you sure can achieve that by passing `n` as a parameter in the constructor.

```
class RVector
{
    double[] v;

    public RVector(double[] d, int n) {
        this.v = new double[n];
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: remove the `<int n>` from the constructor, please!

Answer (score 2):

Java's generics is not totally the same as templates. Hence you cannot put a value in `<>`. It must be a type.

One workaround for this is to pass `n` to the constructor:

```
public RVector(int n, double[] d) {
    ...
}
```

But with this, you can't ensure "type safety" at compile time, not to mention that the you can't constraint the `double[]`'s length to be `n`.

Another workaround would be to create multiple vector classes:

```
public class Vector1D {
    public Vector1D(double value) { ... } 
}

public class Vector2D {
    public Vector2D(double value1, double value2) { ... }
}

public class Vector3D {
    public Vector3D(double value1, double value2, double value3) { ... }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is there something wrong with my English? Sorry if I got some grammar wrong...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh oops! Thanks for pointing that out! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with Generics.

Seems to be a constructor parameter instead of each instance or each class having a method returning the size of the vector